# Are there any feat combinations that would let you fire two hand crossbows or two pistols as a standard action?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, feats, actions, ranged-attack, two-weapon-fighting

Are there any feat combinations that would allow a character dual-wielding hand crossbows or pistols to fire both as a standard action?

Comment: Do you mean standard crossbows, which require both hands? Or are you talking about dual-wielding hand crossbows?

Comment: Yes, I meant it for dual wielding hand crossbows. Not the standard light crossbow, which can fired single handed or using both. I'm sorry for the confusion.

Comment: No problem. I cleaned up the question to make that a little more obvious.

Answer (score 2):

The [Dual Strike option of the Weapon Trick combat feat](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/weapon-trick-combat/#Dual_Strike) says:

> **Additional Prerequisite(s):** Double Slice, Improved Vital Strike
>
> As a standard action, you can make two attacks, one with each weapon you’re wielding, applying the normal penalties for two-weapon fighting to each.

If you're considering options other than feats, the [Two-Weapon Warrior](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/fighter/archetypes/paizo-fighter-archetypes/two-weapon-warrior) Fighter archetype also gets it at 9th level.